# How to choose a $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices uniformly at random?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $n\geq 1$ be an even number and $d\geq 1$ be integers.

In [these](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/expanders2016/lecture19.pdf) notes by Luca Trevisan, we see a procedure of coming up with a $d$-regular on $n$ vertices on the first page.

The procedure is: Let $V=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.

> Choose $d$ perfect matchings on $V$ (uniformly?) at random and take the union of these matchings.

It is not clear as to how this procedure gives rise to a $d$-regular graph. Two different matchings can share an edge. So unless we are allowing multiple edges (which I am pretty sure we are not), this does not seem to make sense.

Can somebody clarify what is happening here?

Comment: Whether the above randomized constructions result in a $d$-regular *simple* graphs or a $d$-regular *multigraphs with parallel edges*, is fine either way. The main point is that such a construction has great expansion, i.e., small subsets $S$ have many neighbors outside of themselves.

Comment: ..and from looking at the notes a bit further, it appears that Luca Trevisan was just trying to make the point as expediently as possible that good expanders are quite easy to construct via random methods [standard stuff]--so he can move on to the connection between the 2nd largest eigenvalue and expansion, and then later *explicit* constructions of expanders, which are far more iinvolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the idea in the lecture notes is just to allow parallel edges. But we can achieve an actual reasonable distribution with the same properties by sampling a union of $d$ disjoint matchings, chosen uniformly at random. In practice, this can be done by picking $d$ matchings uniformly and rejecting if an edge appears in more than one of them.

(Note that by default, we must start over from the beginning if this happens; the similar-looking algorithm which goes through the matchings one at a time, and keeps sampling the $i^{\text{th}}$ matching until it is disjoint from the previous $i-1$, does not produce the same distribution. No idea if it produces a sufficiently similar distribution to be worth doing anyway.)

This is a reasonable model for two reasons:

1. The failure probability is not too high; with a constant probability depending on $d$, a uniformly chosen set of $d$ matchings is disjoint.
2. The model is *contiguous* to the uniform: a statement holds with probability tending to $1$ in this model, if and only if it holds with probability tending to $1$ for a uniformly chosen $d$-regular graph. (In both cases, as $n \to \infty$.)

Regarding the first point: the probability that two uniformly chosen edges are equal is $\frac{1}{\binom n2} \sim \frac{2}{n^2}$. In the union-of-$d$-matchings model, there are $\binom d2 n^2$ pairs of edges we have to worry about, so the expected number of collisions is $\binom d2 n^2 \cdot \frac{2}{n^2} = d(d-1)$. These collisions are so close to independent that their distribution is asymptotically Poisson; in particular, the chance of getting no collisions is $e^{-d(d-1)}+o(1)$. This may seem bad, but it is remarkable in that the limit does not depend on $n$.

Regarding the second point: there are several such contiguity results known, which are summarized [in these slides](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/MAA2005/L5.pdf). Let $\mathcal G_{n,d}$ be the uniform distribution on $d$-regular graphs. Then the relevant result from these slides is that $\mathcal G_{n,d}$ is contiguous with $\mathcal G_{n,d-1} \oplus \mathcal G_{n,1}$ for all $d\ge 2$, where $\oplus$ denotes this try-it-until-it-works disjoint superposition. As a corollary, $\mathcal G_{n,d}$ is contiguous with $\mathcal G_{n,1}^{\oplus d}$, which is the model used here - because $\mathcal G_{n,1}$ is precisely a uniformly chosen matching.

In particular, though this does not appear to be mentioned in those lecture notes (yet?), proving an a.a.s. expansion result for $\mathcal G_{n,1}^{\oplus d}$ is the same as proving it for $\mathcal G_{n,d}$.

Moreover, proving this result in the union-of-matchings model without resampling if the matchings fail to be disjoint also achieves the same result. Conditioning on an event with probability $e^{-d(d-1)}$ can increase the probability that the graph is not an expander by at most a factor of $e^{d(d-1)}$, and $e^{d(d-1)} \cdot O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ is still $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$.

Comment: Very interesting post. I'll try my best to absorb all of this. The concept of contiguity and the theorems around it are very beautiful and meaningful. I'll probably need to bother you about this for the next few days. I hope that's okay.

Comment: Can you please help me with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949870/creating-a-uniform-distribution-on-the-set-of-all-r-regular-graphs-on-n-vert

Comment: Thanks for answering the previous question. I have another. I am trying understand the first paragraph of your answer and point (2) that follows. Let $M$ be the set of all the perfect matchings of $V=[n]$ with the uniform distribution. So we have the product space $M^d$. Choosing $d$ matchings uniformly at random is same as picking a point in $M^d$. We reject a member of $M^d$ if two edges repeat. The "rejection" bit is throwing me off. Is the formal meaning this: (contd.)

Comment: (contd). Consider the subset $S$ of $M^d$ which consists of all the members of $M^d$ that do not give rise to multiple edges when we take the union of the $d$-matchings. Define a map $S\to \mathcal G(n, d)$, where $\mathcal G(n, d)$ is the set of all the $d$-regular graphs on $[n]$, which sends a tuple $(F_1, \ldots, F_d)$ in $S$ to the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^d F_i$. Now consider the push-forward measure on $\mathcal G(n, r)$ under this map, where the measure of $S$ is the one borrowed from $M^d$ by restriction. (contd).

Comment: (contd).  This push-forward measure is not a probability measure. So normalize it to get a probability measure, call this measure $\mu_n$. So for each $n$ we get a probability measure $\mu_n$ on $\mathcal G(n, r)$. Then the model $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3, \ldots)$ is contiguous with the uniform probability measure model on $\mathcal G(n, r)$'s.

Comment: I don't know what a push-forward measure is. The rejection bit means "condition on no repeated edges"; algorithmically, we can implement it by sampling an element of $M^d$ over and over until we get one with no repeated edge.

Comment: Let me define the push-forward measure. Suppose $X$ be a finite set with $\mu$ a probability distribution (aka probability measure) on it. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map from $X$ into a finite set $Y$. Then we can create a probability distro on $Y$ as follows: For each $y$ in $Y$, we write $\nu(y)$ to mean $\mu(f^{-1}(y))$. Then one can see that $\nu$ is a probability distro on $Y$. In general, $\mu$ may not be a probability measure but any measure. We can still push it forward in the same way and get a measure on $Y$.

Comment: Also, can you express formally what is meant by "condition on no repeated edges". The meaning that I can think of is the same as I had articulated earlier in the language of push-forward. Can you see if that what you mean or something else. Aslo, can the phrase "sampling from $M^d$ over and over" be made precise? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it is the same. The phrase "sampling from $M_d$ over and over" is precise. Step 1: Sample from $M_d$. Step 2: check if there are any repeated edges; if there are, go back to Step 1.

Comment: Under this iterative definition, what I am unable to form the meaning of is the following phrase: "What is the probability that a given $d$-regular graph $G$ is obtained when one performs the rejection-recipe." Or perhaps asking for this probability is somehow the wrong question?

Comment: It's not the wrong question, but there is no nice exact formula for the probability. It is proportional to the number of ways to decompose $G$ into $d$ matchings (because that is how many different elements of $M^d$ can produce the graph).

Comment: Okay. I follow so far. The next thing I do not understand is the line "these collisions are so close to independent that their distribution is asymptotically Poisson". Can you elaborate on this. I am lost here.

Comment: This was not meant to be a proof, rather an assertion. If the collisions were independent, then the number of collisions would be distributed binomially with mean $d(d-1)$, and as $n \to \infty$ a binomial with a constant mean approaches the Poisson distribution. Here, we are sufficiently close to independence that the same thing holds in the limit. One possible proof relies on showing the convergence of the $k^{\text{th}}$ moment for all constant $k$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess now I more or less understand your post. I am working through the proofs of contiguity theorems that are relevant to my question. For the things I yet do not understand, I will start separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that they consider $n$ to be much bigger than $d$. In that case, the chance of matchings overlapping is sufficiently small, so that you can assume that they don't (or you compute a few more until they don't, if needed).
It is common in some lectures, especially more practical ones, to neglect such special cases, given that their chance is small enough; although that is sometimes hard to get used to coming from a strong theoretical, mathematical background.

Comment: The chance of matchings overlapping does not go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov you are correct that the chances of matchings overlapping does not go to 0 for $n$ large. But you would expect $\theta(d)$ parallel edges in the entire graph, with the probability that there is a vertex $v$ is incident to 3 or more parallel matchings to be $\le n \times O(d^2n^{-2})$.  More to the point if this is a lecture about how $d$ random perfect matchings make great expanders, you could show that with high probability the resulting graph is such that small subsets do indeed expand by $> d/2$, matchings overlapping or not.